# The transverse root for a vector field

Tags: differential-topology

I encountered the term, so may I ask - what is the transverse root for a vector field?

Thank you~

Comment: Do you have any context?

Comment: Thanks @IanColey - I am given a vector field, and asked to show there are $k$ transverse zeros of index -1.